# Which hibernate jar has the OracleDialect class?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to install GridSphere through some app, there's an ant task that creates a database. So I changed the hibernate.properties file to use Oracle (instead of HSQL) but i'm getting this error:

```
 net.sf.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
```

My dialect setting is:

```
      hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

I'm using Oracle10g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `net.sf` package of the exception, I am guessing that you are using Hibernate 2. When it was in version 2, Hibernate was hosted on sourceforge and was released with the `net.sf.hibernate` package. From version 3 they started using the `org.hibernate` package. So the dialect you should be using is `net.sf.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect` or `net.sf.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect`, instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect`. You can still find older 2.x hibernate releases (with sources and documentation) on the [sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/).

Answer (score 0):

This class should be in Hibernate core. Check out the [source tree](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/). What version of Hibernate are you using?

Also, you might want to use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` in your case.